# A conjecture on shape optimization for Dirichlet-Laplacian

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, sp.spectral-theory, laplacian

For a given domain $G$, with sufficiently smooth boundary, in the plane we denote the first two eigenvalues of Dirichlet-Laplacian on $G$ of by $\lambda_1(G)$ and  $\lambda_2(G)$.

$\textbf{Open(?) problem. } $Let $D$ be a box and consider the following set:
$$A_\alpha=\{\Big(\lambda_1(\Omega),\lambda_2(\Omega)\Big):\,\,\Omega\subset D, |\Omega|\leq \alpha\},$$ 
where $\alpha>0$ is fixed and $|.|$ denotes the area measure. Show (or give counterexample) that $A$ is convex.
$\textbf{Remark 1.}$ If we mimic this problem for an interval of finite length it is very easy to observe that the corresponding set $A$ is indeed convex.

$\textbf{Remark 2.}$ In [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1991-25-01/S0273-0979-1991-16016-7/S0273-0979-1991-16016-7.pdf) M. Ashbaugh and R.Benguria show that this set is convex in the $x$ and the $y$ direction. See also [my favorite survey on this topic](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00115548/document) by A. Henrot and [also this paper](http://rspa.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/467/2130/1577).

Has been any progress been made towards resolving this problem?